# How to mock axios with useQuery using Jest in React application

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, tanstackreact-query

I have compomponent and within this component I make a call to backend service and receive data:

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

export const Products = () => {
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['products'],
    queryFn: () =>
      axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/client/products`).then((res) => res.data)
  });
...
```

But when I try to create a Unit Test:

```
test('products shown on page', () => {
  render(<Products />);
});
```

I get this error:

```
  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      3 | import { Product } from '../../components/Product';
      4 | import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
    > 5 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
```

I have already tried to to use `jest.mock(axios)` and `jest.spyOn(@tanstack/react-query, 'useQuery')` but error is still being shown, please help me to solve this problem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is related to the fact that Jest doesn't support ES6 import statements by default. To solve this problem, you can use Babel to transpile your code to ES5 syntax, which Jest can understand.

To configure Babel with Jest, you'll need to install the following packages:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-jest
```

Then, create a babel.config.js file in the root of your project and add the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
};
```

Next, you need to update your Jest configuration in package.json to use Babel:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Now Jest will use Babel to transpile your code before running tests.

To mock the useQuery hook from @tanstack/react-query, you can use jest.mock as follows:

```
jest.mock('@tanstack/react-query', () => ({
  useQuery: jest.fn(() => ({ isLoading: false, data: [] }))
}));
```

This will mock the useQuery hook to always return an object with isLoading set to false and an empty array for data.

To mock axios, you can use jest.mock as follows:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [] }))
}));
```

This will mock the axios.get function to always return a promise that resolves to an object with an empty array for data.

Putting it all together, your test file should look like this:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Products } from './Products';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('@tanstack/react-query', () => ({
  useQuery: jest.fn(() => ({ isLoading: false, data: [] }))
}));

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [] }))
}));

test('products shown on page', () => {
  render(<Products />);
});
```

With these changes, your test should run successfully without the import error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering without trying to execute any code, so sorry if it does work.

You can use [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/fr/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) from the jest object. To do so :

```
import axios from 'axios';

test('products shown on page', () => {
  jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({data: ...}))
  render(<Products />);
})
```

and so now, you can make `axios.get` return whatever you want in `mockReturnValue`.

Acknowledge that the mock does not handle the `.then((res) => res.data)` treatment into your `queryFn` anonymous function, and so it will be executed after. That's why I wrapped the `...` into an object with data as an attribute.